# Programatically Detecting if an android device has an SD card slot

Tags: android

I would like to know if it is possible to find out if the phone has an SD card SLOT or not. If it has, what is the max supported size.

Please note, my questions is not how to check if the SD Card is currently mounted or not, i am aware that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Environmental variable "SECONDARY_STORAGE" to find out is there any SD card slot. Regarding SD card size, StatFs could provide you such info.

SD card

```
String secondaryStorage = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
if (secondaryStorage == null) {
    secondaryStorage = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE")
}
```

SD card size (not a SD card slot size, I am not aware is it doable, thanks to greenapps for comment):

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()); 
long size = statFs.getBlockCountLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong();
```

Docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html

Comment: On my Nexus 5, there is no SD slot but I have an external storage directory, there is a virtual "SD Cards" that is linked to the internal storage

Comment: Your Nexus 5 should return null for `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")`. It should return valid path for `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE")`.

Comment: Sorry, I was speaking about the SD card size.

Comment: To correct my previous comment, your Nexus 5 should return valid path for `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")`. To answer on your comment, you can always combine `secondaryStorage != null` and/or `externalSdcardStorage != null` with statFs stuff.

Comment: Of course, I know that, but you should be more precise about that in the answer ;)

Comment: That way we would not have this nice discussion. :) I will keep it in mind for next time... Thanks!

Comment: 'You can try with Environmental variable "SECONDARY_STORAGE" to find out is there any SD card slot.'. No. Nonsense. That will mostly return null even if a SD card is inserted.

Comment: If `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") == null` try with `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE")`

Comment: Trying in that way still is nonsense. You will not detect a SLOT with it. And for determining size: your code can be used to determine the size of a SD card. But is useless to determine the maximum size of an SD card that can be used in a device. Please read the question better.

Comment: Based on my limited set of devices with SD card slot (Samsung GT I9100 and Sony Xperia T LT30p), I don't agree that `SECONDARY_STORAGE` and/or `EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE` will return null. Since you are stating that will mostly return null, hope that is not nonsense, that you have try it. I agree that second part of question is not answered correctly, I am not aware how maximum size of card slot can be queried. I have edited my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: To correct myself, for those devices `SECONDARY_STORAGE` and/or `EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE` will not be a null even if the card is not mounted.